# How to use GROUP BY with Firebird?

Tags: group-by, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm trying create a SELECT with GROUP BY in Firebird but I can't have any success. How could I do this ?

**Exception**

```
Can't format message 13:896 -- message file C:\firebird.msg not found.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause).
(49,765 sec)
```

**trying**

```
SELECT FA_DATA, FA_CODALUNO, FA_MATERIA, FA_TURMA, FA_QTDFALTA,
               ALU_CODIGO, ALU_NOME,
               M_CODIGO, M_DESCRICAO,
               FT_CODIGO, FT_ANOLETIVO, FT_TURMA
               FROM FALTAS Falta
               INNER JOIN ALUNOS Aluno ON (Falta.FA_CODALUNO = Aluno.ALU_CODIGO)
               INNER JOIN MATERIAS Materia ON (Falta.FA_MATERIA = Materia.M_CODIGO)
               INNER JOIN FORMACAOTURMAS Turma ON (Falta.FA_TURMA = Turma.FT_CODIGO)
               WHERE (Falta.FA_CODALUNO = 238) AND (Turma.FT_ANOLETIVO = 2015) 
               GROUP BY Materia.M_CODIGO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple use of group by in firebird,group by all columns

```
 select * from T1 t
where t.id in
(SELECT t.id FROM T1 t 
 INNER JOIN T2 j  ON j.id = t.jid 
 WHERE t.id = 1
 GROUP BY t.id)
```

Comment: with Firebird I need use GROUP BY with all columns ? for example if I want use GROUP BY only to `id` does not work ?

Comment: @FernandoPaiva I suggest you describe what you want to achieve, because grouping by a column without aggregate functions doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Using `GROUP BY` doesn't make sense in your example code. It is only useful when using aggregate functions (+ some other minor uses). In any case, Firebird requires you to specify all columns from the `SELECT` column list except those with aggregate functions in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Note that this is more restrictive than the SQL standard, which allows you to leave out functionally dependent columns (ie if you specify a primary key or unique key, you don't need to specify the other columns of that table).

You don't specify why you want to group (because it doesn't make much sense to do it with this query). Maybe instead you want to `ORDER BY`, or you want the first row for each `M_CODIGO`.